# Javascript Regex - ignoring certain characters between 2 chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a need to split a string on space character (' ') but **while excluding any spaces** that come within 2 specific characters (say single quotes).

Here is an example string:

> This-is-first-token This-is-second-token 'This is third token'

The output array should look like this:

```
[0] = This-is-first-token
[1] = This-is-second-token
[2] = 'This is third token'
```

Question:
Can this be done elegantly with regular expression?

Comment: I am not sure that this is elegant but `/[a-zA-Z-]+|['"][\sa-zA-Z-]+['"]/g`

Comment: @Deck. Wow, can you please explain what this does? Im looking at a Cheat Sheet (from Regexlib dot com) and I still can't figure it out.

Comment: FYI, I don't find a complicated regex that is hard to understand exactly what it does without being a regex expert to be an "elegant" solution.  Not sure what you meant when you said "elegant" in the question as that's a bit in the eye of the beholder, but keep in mind that a complicated single line of code is not always the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: Well, a regex being a standard thing, in my opinion it is elegant (even if I personally cant read it). In addition, any one liner is likely more elegant compared a function that is comparatively less efficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Short Answer:

A simple regex for this purpose would be:

```
/'[^']+'|[^\s]+/g
```

## Sample code:

```
data = "This-is-first-token This-is-second-token 'This is third token'";
data.match(/'[^']+'|[^\s]+/g);
```

Result:

```
["This-is-first-token", "This-is-second-token", "'This is third token'"]
```

## Explanation:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3c7m-lorSpW8JfbW)

I think this is as simple as you can make it in just a regex.

The `g` at the end makes it a global match, so you get all three matches.  Without it, you get only the first string.

`\s` matches all whitespace (basically,  and tabs, in this instance).  So, it would work even if there was a tab between `This-is-first-token` and `This-is-second-token`.

To match content in braces, use this:

```
data.match(/\{[^\}]+\}|[^\s]+/g);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GnhUi4EOBe6KHvrp)

Braces or single quotes:

```
data.match(/\{[^\}]+\}|'[^']+'|[^\s]+/g);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aypK0eNBMk5o9Y0T)

Comment: Don't think you need the parens.

Comment: I would use `[^\s]+` instead of `[^ ]+`

Comment: I am trying to test this in regexlib's retester.aspx.

Comment: If I use this '[^']+'|[^\s]+ then it appears to work. So what is the /g part of the regex for?

Comment: im using regexlib's regex testeer. when I add /g then I only get the third token string. if I exclude it then I get all 3.

Comment: why use [^\s] instead of [^ ]   ?

Comment: That's a quirk of the tester.  If you run the code above in actual JavaScript without `/g`, you will only get one match.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41597/discussion-between-alvinfromdiaspar-and-ed-cottrell)

Comment: Ok, how to do this same expression if instead of single quote I want open and closed curly braces? Ex:data = "This-is-first-token This-is-second-token {This is third token}";

Answer (score 3):

You can use this split:

```
var string = "This-is-first-token This-is-second-token 'This is third token'";
var arr = string.split(/(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)\s+/);
//=> ["This-is-first-token", "This-is-second-token", "'This is third token'"]
```

This assumes quotes are all balanced.

Comment: @jfriend00: Never claimed elegance but requirement warrants this kind of regex.

Comment: OP asked for an elegant solution.

Comment: Once again elegance is pretty subjective thing. Different programmers can claim different things elegant.

Comment: Don't mistake elegance for readability. Although to me this regex is somewhat cryptic, it is still far more elegant than a function full of string manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following:

```
"This-is-first-token This-is-second-token 'This is third token'".match(/('[A-Za-z\s^-]+'|[A-Za-z\-]+)/g)
["This-is-first-token", "This-is-second-token", "'This is third token'"]
```